# Stuck in c# web service communication

Tags: c#, web-services, com

I have this [web service](http://ws.serviciosaustrales.com.ar/v3.5/wsdl). 
The EasySoap built in powerbuilder 12.5 can't support this xml, that's why I started to develop a dll in C# to call from powerbuilder. 
I used SoapUI to generate the C# code like this:

```
namespace proxy_ws {
    using System;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    [Guid("some guid")]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.6.1055.0")]
    [System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="v3.5Binding", Namespace="urn:v3.5")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface IV35Binding {

        [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute()]
        [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute("urn:v3.5WSDL#valConsultar", RequestNamespace="urn:v3.5WSDL", ResponseNamespace="urn:v3.5WSDL")]
        [return: System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("return")]
        string valConsultar(string Prestadora, string Usuario, string Clave, string IdPrestador, string FechaDesde, string FechaHasta, string IdEmpresa, string AfiliadoNombre, string AfiliadoNumero, string ValidacionNumero, string IdEstado);
    }
}
```

I never worked on C# before, but I'm sure I'll need some kind of class to call like this:

```
[ProgId(“proxy_ws.IV35Binding”)]
public class Cproxy_ws: IV35Binding
```

But if I try to write it on c#.net, it throws me this error:

```
Error   3   'proxy_ws.IV35Binding.valConsultar(string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string)' “must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial”
```

But I need this because in powerbuilder, I need it to call it like this:

> global external function:

```
Function string Sen(String pPrestadora, String pUsuario, String pClave, String pIdPrestador, String pFechaDesde, String pFechaHta, String pIdEmpresa, String pAfiliadoNombre, String pAfiliadoNumero, String pValidacionNumero, String pIdEstado) library "proxy_ws.dll" alias for "valConsultar;ansi"
```

> And the code:

```
iole = CREATE OLEObject
li_rc = iole.ConnectToNewObject('proxy_ws.IV35Binding')
IF li_rc <> 0 THEN
     DESTROY iole
else
```

Edit:

I need the C# code like a dll just to call the internal functions from power.

Comment: using c# you have to add reference service option below project name. then paste the service link in there and if succeed you can communicate the existing web service eventually.

Comment: the problems was on the xml contract. thats why the 3th part apps can build an usable C# code.
finally, they gave another link, i did the same and worked fine :P
ty for reply.